# Extension Error Swift 3 JSON

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to migrate my app to Swift 3 but I have troubles.

The code section that struggles me is:

```
extension JSON: Swift.BooleanType {

//Optional bool
public var bool: Bool? {
    get {
        switch self.type {
        case .bool:
            return self.object.boolValue
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    set {
        if newValue != nil {
            self.object = NSNumber(value: newValue! as Bool)
        } else {
            self.object = NSNull()
        }
    }
}
```

On first line is where xCode throws an error:

```
extension JSON: Swift.BooleanType {
```

The error says: `Inheritance from non-protocol type 'BooleanType' (aka 'Bool')`

Does anybody know what's happening there?

Comment: Nothing happens, it throws the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is here,

> Bad : extension JSON: Swift.BooleanType {
>
> Good : extension JSON: {
>
> Reason : Admittedly, I am using this to modify SwiftyJSON which is a framework for processing JSON data. In doing some research it seems that they didn't allow BooleanType to allow for inheritance.  The suggested means of dealing with this is simply to remove the type.

link is given : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53405

Answer (score 1):

Protocols are Swift's equivalent of Java interfaces.  If you've never worked with interfaces before, they're classes absent of any concrete implementation.  They exist to describe the skeleton of a class (the attribute and method names it should have) without actually implementing them so that other classes that inherit from the interface can flesh them out later.  In Swift they're particularly useful for implementing the Delegate pattern.

Boolean is not a protocol.  It is very much a living, breathing concrete Type with an existing implementation.  To do what you want to do you either need to override the existing get/set method for Boolean type or create your own Boolean type as described in the [official Apple Swift Blog.](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8)